# How to estimate the time for spinlock holing/waiting time?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm doing a research on spinlock in Linux kernel.
And I need to estimate the time for lock holding and lock waiting.
To do that, I first tried to modify the spinlock function (arch_spin_lock())
but I could not modify that function because I could not build the kernel.
This function was originally an inline function, but I think it was a problem because I made the function too long.

After I already did googling enough, I could not find any way to do that.
So I'm asking this question.
Is there a way to achieve that goal?
I think there is a way to use msr or a system utility.

Please give me some hint.

Thannks!

Comment: Maybe `Documentation/locking/lockstat.txt` in the kernel source tree could be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `man perf-lock` (or its [online page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-lock.1.html))

> I think there is a way to use msr or a system utility.

`perf` uses MSR and is a system utility, so I suppose that's the way you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's common sense.  Not a question of delay size.  A spinlock is a busywait, so it must be considered only in cases you cannot wait in another way.  As when you are in a state where you cannot put a process to wait.  When you are running a hardware interrupt, you are normally interrupting a running process that has no context in common with the device driver you are running on behalf.  More on, you probably have to block some resources, because the process making use of the driver resources can be actually running in another processor, and can be using those resources.  So after checking that this is the case, you have only one possibility, that is, running on a tight loop while waiting the other cpu (and the process dealing with the shared driver resources) terminates accessing them.  This is the typical scenario you'll get for a spinlock to be neccessary.

When unix (and linux) was unable to run multiprocessor, no need for spinlocks was necessary, as you decided (in as single thread) when and how you can be interrupted.  The mechanism to protect the shared resources between interrupt code and main driver code was to block interrupts (from the device driver main code) before accessing the shared resource, and reenabling them, after accessing the common resources.  From the interrupt code, there's no need to block the resource, as interrupts from the device are automatically blocked until you are able to continue without having the resource blocked, then you reenable interrupts.  But once the code can be run on different processors, you lose this restriction, and spinlocks have to be considered.